# JQGrid is not loading data in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid  and table is working correctly. But no data is loading and it continuesly displaying "loading...". It worked correctly but i maybe due to some reason it is not working now.

```
public JsonResult GetDetails()
        {
            Database1Entities db = new Database1Entities();


            var jsondata = new
            {
                total = 1,
                page = 1,
                records = db.Employees.ToList().Count.ToString(),
                rows = db.Employees.Select(a => new {
                a.Id,a.Name,a.Designation,a.Address,a.Salary
                })
            };

            return Json(jsondata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

JQGrid function is below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Grid").jqGrid({
        url: '/Home/GetDetails',
        datatype: 'json',
        myType: 'GET',
        colNames: ['id','Name', 'Designation', 'Address', 'Salary'],
        colModel: [

            { key: false, name: 'Id', index: 'Id',  },
            { key: false, name: 'Name', index: 'Name', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'Designation', index: 'Designation', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'Address', index: 'Address', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'Salary', index: 'Salary', editable: true }

        ],
        jsonReader: {
            root: 'rows',
            page: 'page',
            total: 'total',
            records: 'records',
            id: '0',
            repeatitems: false
        },
        pager: $('#pager'),
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        width: 600,
        viewrecords: true,
        multiselect: true,
        sortname: 'Id',
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption: 'Employee Records',
        loadonce: true,

    }).navGrid('#pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true },
    {
        zIndex: 100,
        url: '/Home/Edit',
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        recreateForm: true,
        afterComplete: function (response) {
            if (response.responseText)
            {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        }
    },
    {
        zIndex: 10,
        url: '/Home/Add',
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        recreateForm: true,
        afterComplete: function (response) {
            if (response.responseText) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        }
    },
    {
        zIndex: 100,
        url: '/Home/Delete',
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        recreateForm: true,
        afterComplete: function (response) {
            if (response.responseText) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        }
    }

    );

});
```

If i add something, it works and data is inserted into database but the main problem is not data is shown in JQGrid. What is the problem?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use? Which web browser you use for tests? It's extremely important for troubleshooting of loading problems. If you have problem with *loading* of grid that you can remove (or comment) the second part of posted code starting with `navGrid`. Moreover the code contains the same errors like your old code. I wrote you that there are no `myType` option, that `jsonReader` which you use is wrong and so on. It's better it you fix clear error in the code. Which error you have exactly if you start the code in debugger (press F12 in web browser and start debugging)?

Comment: @Oleg you have wonderful knowlege about JQGrid...
Now my grid + subgrid works fine. thanks for helping

Comment: When i searched some problem of JQGrid , i found the solution and you solved every problem of JQGrid....